# PHP.ini custom settings through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, php.ini

I'm confused by this ini list in the PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

I want to set some custom php.ini values through htaccess, but which one of these commands is not going to work?

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M

php_value max_execution_time 3

php_value max_input_time 3

php_value memory_limit 2M

php_value post_max_size 1M

php_value open_basedir "/scripts"

php_flag allow_url_fopen 0

php_flag allow_url_include 0

php_flag file_uploads 0

php_value disable_functions 'apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_exec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_set, phpinfo, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore, inject_code, mysql_pconnect, openlog, passthru, php_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_decode, curl_exec, curl_multi_exec, parse_ini_file, show_source, pcntl_fork, pcntl_exec, session_start, getmyuid, getmypid, leak, listen, diskfreespace, tmpfile, link, fopen, unlink, mkdir, file_get_contents, file, fread, rmdir, readfile, file_put_contents, fwrite, delete, fscanf, ignore_user_abort, dl'
```

Comment: Before someone drops an answer, can we find out your current setup - are you running Apache with suPHP? DSO?

Based on your critieria above, you may want have to verify on the values stated in the disable_functions declaration. They look largely intact and should not get in your way.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. In the end I couldn't set them because they were only in the INI. But I could set them up when creating a CLI inside a script.

Comment: It is great to know that you have managed to work it out on your end. Have a great day!